# Changing the root folder via .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've got a shared hosting account associated with a domain name and the root folder (correct me if that's the wrong term) is set to `/` so that all files on the server are public / accessible through the browser.

Can I use .htaccess or something to change the root folder to something like `/example.com/public/`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, the following should work

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect all requests that do not begin with `/public/` to URL that does.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, @clmarquart! What if we need to keep `/example.com/` to go to `/example.com/index.html` or `/example.com/index.php`?

Comment: It can also be advantageous to add RewriteBase / before your RewriteCond. Especially if you are using VirtualDocumentRoot directives.

Answer (score 7):

This is how i always use it in my framework:

```
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /example.com/public/$1 [L,NC]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteRule !^example.com/public/(.*) /example.com/public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 6):

The [DocumentRoot directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot) can't be set in a .htaccess file, only in the server config. As you most likely don't have the privileges to modify the server settings your only solution is to use some rewrite magic as [clmarquart already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792153/changing-the-root-folder-via-htaccess/5792440#5792440).

Answer (score 5):

I use bluehost... this is what works for me:
This is helpful when you are on shared hosting, and have multiple domain names.

Your primary domain is set to public_html but your add-on domains are subfolders inside public_html

This makes it so you don't have to have all your primary domain name files be mixed with add-on domain folders... each domain can be in their own folder...

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?PUTYOURDOMAINNAMEHERE.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PUTYOURFOLDERHERE/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /PUTYOURFOLDERHERE/$1  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?PUTYOURDOMAINNAMEHERE.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ PUTYOURFOLDERHERE/ [L]
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /example/public/$1 [L]
```