# Absolute Path for Deployment in a Non-Root Location

Tags: html, apache, deployment, web-deployment

I typically refer to any assets on my site using *absolute path* so that I don't have to worry about the location of the assets relative to current file.

```
<!-- Using a absolute path. -->
<img src="/images/flag.png" />
<!-- Using a relative path. -->
<img src="../../../images/flag.png" />
```

However, this time I need to host the site at a non-root location e.g. `http://my-server.com/holiday/`.

How would I go about this? I am looking for a solution that doesn't require me to change the path in my files. How do I configure the server (Apache) to treat `http://my-server.com/holiday/` as a "root"?

**Clarification:**
I still need `http://my-server.com/` to behave "normally". That is, it should still point to `http://my-server.com/index.html` i.e. doesn't get redirected to `http://my-server.com/holiday/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to say this but none of the above provides the solution. The answers by @Zoltan and @stslavik were close but, unfortunately, didn't work when deployed; I wished one of them worked, though.

As a result, I resorted to using a combination of [named constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) and [include files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) in PHP. More details: [File Structure for a PHP Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8161389/583539). Note that it doesn't have to be PHP; you can use other languages that provide similar features. +1 for @margusholland whose answer led me to experiment with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re using Apache, there one rather simple thing you could do by just using an SSI variable in your paths.
Do a global replace of all src="/ to something like

```
src="<!--#echo var="prefix" -->/
```

and then in your htaccess for the specific folder define the prefix variable as /holiday

For sites that don’t have the variable or SSI, it’ll just show up as a comment or you can define it as an empty string.

Of course this means you’ll have to turn on SSI in Apache.

Comment: If SSI isn't enabled, where would you define `prefix` as an empty string?

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, assuming this would work, it won't work nicely with _heredoc_ nor _nowdoc_, which you'll find pretty common in a PHP project.

Comment: If SSI isn’t enabled, it’ll just be a comment and ignored anyway.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?DOMAINNAME.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/holiday/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /holiday/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?DOMAINNAME.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ holiday/index.php [L]
```

or take a look here - [Changing the root folder via .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792153/changing-the-root-folder-via-htaccess)

Comment: Do I need to put this .htaccess file on `http://my-server.com/` or `http://my-server.com/holiday/`?

Comment: Thanks guys! I think this is really close to what the solution I was looking for. However, I still want to keep `http://my-server.com/` to go to `http://my-server.com/index.html` or `http://my-server.com/index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is gonna happen for you man, sorry.

You have absolute paths in your documents, and want apache to prepend /holiday to them all without effecting the actual docroot? You can have one or the other, but not both.

You need to either do a mass edit and prepend the directory yourself, or move your images/css/etc into the actual root directory.

mod_rewrite is powerful, but can't really determine intent and parse the same url two different ways depending on what the user wants.

**Edit:**

I am wrong, but I don't have your answer. You may be able to use IS_SUBREQ in mod_rewrite to only apply the re-write conditions for sub-requests from your /holiday/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Easy...

```
# Assuming mod_rewrite is an option...
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   # Turn it on!
   RewriteEngine on

   # If path is /images/flag.png, connect to /holiday/images/flag.png
   RewriteBase /holiday/
</IfModule>
```

Assuming I'm understanding what you mean, this should do you just fine. Point of order, this .htaccess should be in /holiday/

I do this locally on MAMP for testing a website that's base is in `http://localhost:8888/SocialNetwork/` ... If I didn't have that, my absolute paths of, say, `/profile` would go to `http://localhost:8888/profile/` instead of `http://localhost:8888/SocialNetwork/profile`

Comment: I've confirmed that mod_rewrite is turned on. However, this doesn't seem to work. :(

Comment: To find out whether _mod_rewrite_ is turned on: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8242922/583539

Comment: Assuming you use php and apache, if you create a php document saying `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` then visit it with your browser, `mod_rewrite` will appear under "Apache2handler" info, near the top of the document.

Comment: First off, did you place this in your `.htaccess` in `http://my-site.com/holiday/`?

Comment: Yes, I followed your suggestion by heart. :)

Comment: Hmm... I see the problem... The htaccess is read by the time the path is already resolved. You ***might*** be able to do similar with httpd.conf. Alternatively, you could run a script on your php file to seek out all hrefs and prepend with /holiday... I think I'd rather do that before messing with httpd.conf for this...

Comment: Using a script to edit the files in `/holiday/` defeats the purpose of this question. Did it work on your server? If yes, I wonder why the `.htaccess` was read *before* the path resolution on yours, not mine.

Answer (score 0):

what about using html's BASE element? http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4

although i´m not sure how you could have it in a single html file and inherit it to the rest of your htmls, so your source remains intact. 
if your site is html-only maybe with frames, otherwise you could use some sort of server-side include depending on what youre using (asp, jsp, whatever). Check out this link for more information http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

Of course it would work in case you do with php. Adding:

```
<? define(_BASE_, substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/" )) ); ?>

<html>

    <head>
        <script src="<?=_BASE_?>/path_relative_to_project_root"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="<?=_BASE_?>/path_relative_to_project_root">
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: As stated on the question, I was looking for a solution that doesn't require changes in the source code.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a list of filename extensions that should be redirected, you might want to use the rewrite conditions using pattern matching againt the extensions.

Another solutions is to simply create an /images directory under root and let images be downloaded from there. Or have there links to images in your path.