# .htaccess - Setting Per-Directory "Root"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration, apache2

This is my current "shared" server configuration:

```
http://hello.com/ maps to /
# There are a bunch of HTML files under /

http://hello.com/sub-1/ maps to /sub-1/
```

Now I need to upload a new "site" to `http://hello.com/sub-2/`. However, all HTML files in this bundle references the CSS and images using absolute path e.g. `<img src="/images/header.png" />`.

How to configure the server without necessarily changing the site files?

The following discussions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792153/changing-the-root-folder-via-htaccess) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123102/absolute-path-for-deployment-in-a-non-root-location)) have similar nature to this. However, I do **not** want to change the root folder to `http://hello.com/sub-2/`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to really do it without changing all the image references to a relative path (or include sub-2).

A bit of a hacky way could be to use the `-f` flag for `RewriteCond`, changing anything that loads from /images to /sub-1/images or /sub-2/images depending on where the target image exists. An example might be like this:

```
RewriteCond -f sub-1/{$REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule (images/.+) sub-1/$1

RewriteCond -f sub-2/{$REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule (images/.+) sub-2/$1
```

Of course, conflicts in the directories will break everything. My mod_rewrite experience is also a little rusty, so the syntax might not be 100% correct, but you get the idea.

Comment: Any solution that allows us to put the .htaccess in `sub-2` instead of in `/`?