# Laravel 5.1 Code deployment on GoDaddy

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I deployed my Laravel 5.1 code on godaddy. My below Url work but page is blank.

```
http://MyDomainName/public/
```

When I try `http://MyDomainName/public/Categories-List` , it gives 404.

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Why don't you use .htaccess to point the site root to the public folder? isn't more easier to use `http://MyDomainName/Categories-List`?

Comment: Can you suggest the approach for doing this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792153/changing-the-root-folder-via-htaccess

Comment: Is [http://MyDomainName](http://MyDomainName) working? can you share your virtual host configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `.htaccess` file like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```