# Change URL on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I have been working on a WordPress site.
`www.example.com` and the main homepage of my site(`index.html`) says "We're under construction etc." and it's just an image.

For the development of the website, I have been using a different directory - `www.example.com/dev` and everything I have developed has been under `/dev`(`/dev/index.php` etc.)

The website is now ready and I need to point the finsihed website (`www.example.com/dev`) to the actual public site(which is now under `www.example.com`) that I have finished. How do I go about this?

Comment: Why not just copying the files from `/dev` to the root folder? you can also use htaccess to point to another folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792153/changing-the-root-folder-via-htaccess

Comment: A simple copy will break because wordpress uses url's that include the complete path afaik, but you can export your wordpress settings and do a clean install on the root directory, then import your exported files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done 2 ways,

1. You can do this easily by changing site_url in options table. Once you transfer data and change the url your site should be running on the new url. If you have stored static urls in post or pages then, you have to change that as well.
2. Export sql file from phpmyadmin. Now find and replace all urls from old to new ones.

Note: Keep your current development site working as, sometimes it's possible that contact form 7 or any data gets missing. For example, Widgets get in inactive mode sometime.

Once your new website is confirmed then you can remove your old website.

Comment: For the second way you could easily use SQL to change that.
Here is the [how to](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/)

Answer (score 1):

use this code for changing you website url

```
SET @oldsite='http://www.example.com/dev'; 
SET @newsite='http://www.example.com';
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, @oldsite, @newsite) WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, @oldsite, @newsite);
UPDATE wp_links SET link_url = replace(link_url, @oldsite, @newsite);
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, @oldsite, @newsite);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Moving Directories On Your Existing Server**

Wordpress has a wiki page that explained this for you:

[Moving Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Within_Your_Site)

*Here are the step-by-step instructions to move your WordPress site to a new location on the same server:*

1. Create the new location using one of these two options:

   1. If you will be moving your WordPress core files to a new directory,
      create the new directory.
   2. If you want to move WordPress to your root directory, make sure all
      index.php, .htaccess, and other files that might be copied over are
      backed up and/or moved, and that the root directory is ready for the
      new WordPress files.
2. Log in to your site.
3. Go to the `Administration > Settings > General` panel.
4. In the box for WordPress Address (URL): change the address to the
   new location of your main WordPress core files.
5. In the box for Site Address (URL): change the address to the new
   location, which should match the WordPress (your public site)
   address.
6. Click Save Changes.
7. (Do not try to open/view your site now!)
8. Move your WordPress core files to the new location. This includes
   the files found within the original directory, such as
   http://example.com/wordpress, and all the sub-directories, to the
   new location.
9. Now, try to open your site by going to `yourdomain.com/wp-admin`.
   Note, you may need to go to `yourdomain.com/wp-login.php`
10. If you are using Permalinks, go to the `Administration > Settings > Permalinks`

    panel and update your Permalink structure to your
    `.htaccess` file, which should be in the same directory as the main
    `index.php` file.
11. Existing image/media links uploaded media will refer to the old
    folder and must be updated with the new location. You can do this
    with the Better Search Replace plugin, `WP-CLI's` search-replace if
    your hosting provider (or you) have installed `WP-CLI`, manually in
    your SQL database, or by using the 3rd party database updating tool
    Search and Replace Databases Script * Note: this script is best used
    by experienced developers.
12. In some cases your permissions may have changed, depending on your
    ISP. Watch for any files with `0000` permissions and change them
    back to `0644`.
13. If your theme supports menus, links to your home page may still have
    the old subdirectory embedded in them. Go to `Appearance > Menus` and
    update them.
14. Sometimes you would need to restart your server,
    otherwise your server may give out an error. (happens in MAMP
    software (Mac)).
15. It is important that you set the URI locations BEFORE you move the
    files.

**If You Forget to Change the Locations**

*If you accidentally moved the files before you changed the URIs: you have two options.*

1. Suppose the files were originally in `/path/to/old/` and you moved them to `/path/to/new` before changing the URIs. The way to fix this would be to make `/path/to/old/` a symlink (for Windows users, "symlink" is equivalent to "shortcut") to `/path/to/new/`, i.e.

   `ln -s /path/to/new /path/to/old`

   and then follow the steps above as normal. Afterwards, delete the symlink if you want.
2. If you forget to change the WordPress Address and Blog Address, you will be unable to change it using the wordpress interface. However, you can fix it if you have access to the database. Go to the database of your site and find the `wp_options` table. This table stores all the options that you can set in the interface. The WordPress Address and Blog Address are stored as `siteurl` and `home` (the `option_name` field). All you have to do is change the `option_value` field to the correct URL for the records with `option_name=’siteurl‘` or `option_name=’home‘`.

Answer (score 0):

step 1:

Just copy your all files and folder from www.example.com/dev  to www.example.com

step 2:
open your database and in table wp_option

siteurl
http://    www.example.com/dev  to www.example.com/

home
http://  www.example.com/dev  to www.example.com/