# How to remove /public from url in Symfony5 subdir?

Tags: .htaccess, shared-hosting, symfony5

I have a project inside public_html/HELP
but the problem is to access /HELP I need to put /public
I tried various solution that I could find in internet but failed.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
      </IfModule>
```

please provide me solution where I can access /public with just example.com/HELP.
Thanks

Comment: Please do share your htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: I have added please check

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792153/changing-the-root-folder-via-htaccess