# Change ROOT folder directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, server, routes

I want to change root folder directory from **[www.example.com/index.html](http://www.example.com/index.html)** (base directory) to a sub directory **[www.example.com/dist/index.html](http://www.example.com/dist/index.html)** and serve as **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** using .**htaccess** rules

Comment: [Changing the root folder via .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792153/changing-the-root-folder-via-htaccess)

Comment: Thanx @ftrsk but this answer is not good for me ... the use redirect and i want to rewrite  or replace the original directory with a new one

Comment: Can you clarify what problem you're trying to solve? Like, why do you want the default resource to be from a subdirectory of the web root? Why not just change the web root?

Comment: @DonR: Does it really matter? The question can be answered independent of why their specific business requirements call for this functionality.

Comment: @DonR ... the problem is that i have hosted my application on DigitalOcean using my github account , unfortunately my repo contain 2 folders and one file and this file called index so the deployment takes this index as root but my real application inside a folder called dist so DigitalOcean didn't help me out and the only way out is .htaccess ... ihope u understand

Comment: @JeremyCaney The reason it might matter is that the requirement that it not use a redirect made me wonder if this wasn't an XY problem, given that rewriting also works by redirection. I wondered if understanding the bigger picture might not help us come up with a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Example .htaccess file to check:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Your new base directory for files - example index.html
  RewriteBase /dist/

  # Place for your own rules - example with non-www to www, index.html to domain, http to https

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ![0-9]$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/index.(html|htm)$
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```